# How to repair this part of sliding patio doors

Tags: doors, screens

My patio door is beaten up pretty good. this notch that receives the screen (for the lack of a better term, please let me know if it has proper name)  has broken over time. I can't find a replacement in homedepot. Are they something I can repair separately or do I have to replace the whole door?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want to search for "U" channel or Side Jamb Channel. Home depot has some and any window / door specialty shop will have them too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks easy enough to make out of thin metal.

Cut to size needed(5/8 x 5/8 x 5/8) and bend over a 5/8 piece of wood.  Or whatever size is needed.

Prime and paint.

Can cut a bit wider and bend the edges(1/8 to 1/4) over so no sharp edges and a bit more rigid.

I would call it C channel shape, usually used for heavy/thick steel.

Answer (score 0):

Many types of sliding door trim and seals are proprietary to the manufacturer.

Find the manufacturer of the door and see if you can contact them.  If unsuccessful, reach out to local door specialists. In my location there are a few companies that specialize in repairs on sliding doors.  They would be more likely to be able to source parts for repairs and may even have what you need in stock.